# Extract text between patterns in new files

Tags: awk

I'm trying to analyze a file with the following structure:

```
AAAAA
123
456
789
AAAAA
555
777
999
777
```

The idea is to detect the 'AAAAA' pattern and extract the two following lines. After this is done, I would like to append the next 'AAAAA' pattern and the following two lines, so th final file will look something like this:

```
AAAAA
123
456
AAAA
555
777
```

Taking into account that the last one will not end with the 'AAAAA' pattern.

Any idea about how this can be done ? I've use sed but I don't know how to select the number of lines to be retained after the pattern...

Fo example with AWK:

```
awk '/'$AAAAA'/,/'$AAAAA'/' INPUTFILE.txt
```

Bu this will only extract all the text between the two AAAAA

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `grep` command has a flag that prints lines *after* each match. For example:

```
grep AAAAA --after 2 <file>
```

Unless I misunderstood, this should match your requirements, and is much simpler than `awk` scripts.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`

```
sed -n '/AAAAA/{N;N;p}' file.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed '/AAAAA/!d;n;n' file`?

Answer (score 2):

with smart counters

```
$ awk '/AAAAA/{n=3} n&&n--' file

AAAAA
123
456
AAAAA
555
777
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk '$1 == "AAAAA" {n = NR+2} NR <= n' file

AAAAA
123
456
AAAAA
555
777
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works but how can I delete the line number written just at the right of each line ?

Comment: Sorry where are line numbers being written? This just prints each line without any line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

just cheat

```
mawk/mawk2/gawk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "AAAAA\n"; RS = "^$"; 

    } END { for(x=2; x<= NF; x++) { print $(x) } }'
```

no one says the fields must be split by spaces, and rows must be new-lines one-by-one. By design of FS, every field after $1 will contain the matches you need, and fitting multiple "rows" of each within $2 etc.

In this example, in $2 you will find 12 bytes, like this :

```
1 2 3 \n 4 5 6 \n 7 8 9 \n     # spaced out for readability
```